# How to update SQL Server table from ADF?

Tags: sql-server, azure, triggers, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I need to update the Azure SQL Server table if another SQL Server tables is updated.

For example: I have one Azure SQL table `dbo.Azuretable` and I also have a SQL Server table `dbo.sqlservertable`. Both these tables are part of two different SQL Server instances, but the table schema is exactly the same.

What happens is `dbo.sqlservertable` updates on daily basis, let's say every day one row inserts in `dbo.sqlservertable`, I want the same row to be inserted into `dbo.Azuretable` as soon as `dbo.sqlservertable` gets updated. I want to do it Azure if possible or I am open to any other method as well.

What I have done so far:

I created one copy activity which replicates the changes to `dbo.Azuretable` what ever happened in `dbo.sqlservertable`. But I need to manually trigger it because I don't know when my `dbo.sqlservertable` gets updated. I want to automate this process.

Comment: Hey, Can you please state the version of your SQL server which is the source? Depending on the SQL server version, we can think of different scopes

Comment: @Nandan   SQL Server Management Studio 15.0

Comment: Hey, what is the version of your SQL server database is what I meant :) not the SSMS. Please execute Select @@version on the SQL server database and tell me the output

Comment: @Nandan Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8, Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to sync the data :

1. use data sync in azure sql database to sync from sql server to Azure SQL database
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql
2. You can create a trigger on the table in SQL server 2017 on insert,update,delete

and via trigger, call a stored procedure which would export data into blob via polybase.
leverage blob trigger in adf pipeline to sync data from sql server to Azure SQL database

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-versioned-feature-summary?view=sql-server-ver16

Else you can also trigger a SQL server job wherein you can have a powershell logic to generate a file in blob or trigger ADF REST API for pipeline trigger

sample reference my blog:
https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2022/10/01/event-trigger-data-sync-from-sql-server-to-synapse-via-azure-data-factory-synapse-pipeline/

Answer (score 2):

First, you require to find inserted rows. Use except functions.

```
select * from dbo.sqlservertable
except
select * from dbo.Azuretable
```

Then add  to "dbo.Azuretable"

```
WITH new_records AS(
    select * from dbo.sqlservertable
    except
    select * from dbo.Azuretable
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Azuretable
SELECT * FROM new_records
```

You can use data factory or synapse pipeline for it. Pipeline->Activities->General-> **Script** meets your demand. After that you'll see lightning icon names add trigger, click and new/edit. Bring your mouse to choose trigger and click. Now, click new. There are all schedule settings. I hope this solution helps you.

[image]

Comment: Hello @EbruB., I do have the copy activity in place to find and insert the new record. But what I am trying to figure out that, my pipeline should run only when some record is inserted not every 15 mins.

Comment: @NasonThomas , I checked Microsoft documents quickly. It may be done with "copy behavior" in copy data->sink. After you click "add dynamic content" for copy behavior, you'll see system variables. check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables. I'm not sure about solution. I will let you know as soon as I try it out.